# json vs jinja2 templates rendering

Tags: json, flask, jinja2

I'm currently sending data from my flask application to my HTML pages as dicts or list and I use templates rendering to display the values like `{{data[0]}}`, and I'm wondering is it a bad practice? should I use jsonify instead or it's the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering is it a bad practice?

It's not a bad practice. It's what we called template rendering.

> should I use jsonify instead or it's the same thing?

They are not the same thing. `jsonify()` will return a JSON reponse (Content-Type: application/json), while `render_template()` reutrn a HTML respone (Content-Type: text/html). The former pass pure data (for machine), the latter show a HTML page (for human).

Normally, you only use `jsonify` when building a REST API or making AJAX call.